# Nginx two servers were invoked when processing 1 request

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, http

Seeing this in nginx logs:

```
"upstream": "52.86.112.192:443, 52.86.78.197:443",
"upstream_response_time": "7.005, 7.016",
```

The documentation of nginx says:

```
If several servers were contacted during request processing, 
their addresses are separated by commas, 
e.g. “192.168.1.1:80, 192.168.1.2:80, unix:/tmp/sock”.
```

Unfortunately it is not clear to me how can two servers be invoked when processing 1 request? This is w/o internal redirects? Was it a retry after the first attempt failed?

The DNS query returns two A records:

```
xxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 54.84.139.107
xxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 52.71.207.21
```

Does it mean, than nginx does a retry for every failed request automatically? Or can it be configured? (this is AWS so the IP's of the load balancers are changing constantly)

Answer (score 1):

I think one situation is:

> request invoke first backend but it is failed, then invoke next one. if backend all failed ,it return **502**

BTW:this is my case

Comment: I guess it could be the case. Any other cases you might think off. I hope I will have time to test it out.

Comment: i think same case , but if backend connect success ,but return  an error http header, will nginx invoke next backend ? i think this case is extrend .